# Добавить в начало PDF страницы в зависимости от количества страниц

Tags: php, tcpdf

Надо добавить страницы в начало PDF если количество всех страниц не кратно 4.

В конце кода я могу сделать это так:

```
$total = $pdf->getNumPages();
if ($total % 4 != 0) {
  $left_pages =  $total % 4;
  for($i=1; $i<=$left_pages; $i++) {
        $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
  }
}
```

Но в начале кода `$pdf->getNumPages()` равен `0` и этот код не работает. Как получить количество всех страниц в начале или сделать это другим способом?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644353/get-the-number-of-pages-in-a-pdf-document/14644354#14644354

Comment: Это подсчет кол-ва стр готового пдф, это не то

Comment: Думаю можно посмотреть в сторону `$pdf->movePage()`, добавляете страницы и перемещаете их в начало

Comment: @Tunker все верно,  в конец цикла надо добавить $nump = $pdf->getPage(); $pdf->movePage($nump,1);

Comment: Думаю лишнее каждый раз считать страницы, они уже есть в $total: `++$total;  $pdf->movePage($total,1);` Проверка `if ($total % 4 != 0)` тоже лишняя если внутри только цикл который приведен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию перемещения страницы в pdf документе `movePage()`, добавляете необходимые страницы и перемещаете их в начало документа:

```php
$total = $pdf->getNumPages();
$left_pages =  $total % 4;
for ($i=1; $i<=$left_pages; $i++) {
  $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A5');
  ++$total;
  $pdf->movePage($total,1)
}
```